# AngularJS 1.2.13 ng-if does not re-evaluate $resource result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have something like the following in a template:

```
<div ng-if="foo">
   ...
</div>
<div ng-class="foo && 'foo-is-present'">
   ...
</div>
```

In the controller for this scope, I have the following:

`$scope.foo = $resource("path/to/resource").query();`

The resource loads just find and returns a simple JSON array (verified by watching request in Chrome), and other debugging shows that `foo` contains the array, exactly as it should.  The second `div` applies the `foo-is-present` class as expected, however the first `div` still has its `ng-if` evaluating to false, preventing that `div` from rendering.

This doesn't seem right, as I want that first `div` to show up once the results of the resource have been loaded.  What am I missing here?

**EDIT** It turns out `ng-if`'s version of "truthy" does not include arrays, even if the array is not empty.  I was able to work around this by adding turning the condition into `ng-if="!!foo"`, but this feels hacky.  If anyone has any better insight or solutions, please share!

Comment: Why don't you write that as an answer and accept it? People might find it useful.

Comment: Wasn't sure which place was better.  I'll do that, though, so it's more obvious as a workaround.

Comment: True, but if an array always evaluates to false, that's an interesting point for all angular users (although it's hard to believe, I'll test it myself).

Answer (score 0):

Also in the **Edit**, above, but added as an answer so it is more immediately visible as a (hopefully) useful workaround.

---

It turns out ng-if's version of "truthy" does not include arrays, even if the array is not empty. I was able to work around this by adding turning the condition into ng-if="!!foo", but this feels hacky. If anyone has any better insight or solutions, please share!

Answer (score 0):

What version of AngularJS are you using?

I'm using 1.2.10 and:

`$scope.foo = [];
ng-if="foo"`

Evaluates to true.

Perhaps the first div is not within the scope of the controller that contains foo?

Comment: I think I was using the same version.  It could be that ngIf is sensitive to $resource-s in particular, evaluating an incomplete request as falsy (just a guess).  I haven't tried it yet with a plain empty array, but based on your experiment I'm guessing there's more going on here than meets the eye.